# Failed HC-05 Bluetooth sketch upload - (port and board correct)

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, hc-05

I'm running this project with HC-05 https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/millerman4487/view-serial-monitor-over-bluetooth-fbb0e5 and I am getting connection error. I have ensured my port selected and board is accurate but no such luck. The Arduino uno is powered by 3.7v batt (output ~8v with reg) so it is simply just a battery connection and BT module, but when uploading the sketch, it fails. I am relatively new to arduino, and am not sure where to begin this debug.

I am using PC windows, and using a BT dongle receiver for connection (maybe this affects port comm?)

Thanks in advance

Here us the error message

```
Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Uno"

Sketch uses 1954 bytes (6%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.

Global variables use 250 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1798 bytes for local variables. 
Maximum is 2048 bytes.

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for 
suggestions.

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04

avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x04
```

Answer (score 1):

when uploading the code, did you ensure disconnecting the Rx, Tx pins from the Arduino? Coz this is a similar error you get when you upload code with your comm pins connected. Try uploading the code with no wires connected.

Comment: Ok, disconnected Rx, Tx, and was returned with this error

Comment: avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x09

Comment: Restart your IDE and use a different com port for uploading.

Comment: tried, and still no luck